# Idiom request for something has a powerful feature that would make it superior to others

Tags: idiom-requests

Let's say there are several cities that have their own attractions but this particular X city has a great amusement park that would make it superior to the others. How would you paraphrase this in your own words and preferably in an idiomatic way?

Comment: In the world of marketers and startups, this is known as the "UVP", or *unique value proposition*.

Comment: Great info! But that's too technical.

Comment: Yeah, I was suggesting it as a starting point for your search; from there you'd get to "differentiator", etc, and all its synonyms

Comment: I certainly started to look into that! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be ([a  cut above](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+a+cut+above)):

> - to be better than other things or people:

- City X is a cut above all the other cities as regards amusement parks.

(TFD)

Comment: Looks like this one works the best! :)

Answer (score 6):

This city with its attractions, ***[stands head and shoulders above the rest](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stand+head+and+shoulders+above):***

> Fig. [for someone or something] to be considerably superior to someone
>   or something.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of touristic infrastructure, I'd say this city is **second to none**.

> "second to none" - better than anything else [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/second+to+none), above comparison, unmatchable, unequalled,  .